# How to change error messaging when using rm in Ubuntu Server (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, command-line-interface

I want to be able to change my messages
e.g.:

```
student@ubuntuserver: rm -v filename
```

***removed 'file'***--> I want to change this
to for example ***You succesfully removed this file!***
or something else...
Also when something goes wrong with removing the file it normally says:
***No such file or directory!***
I want it to say ***Error when removing file*** or ***could not remove file***

Comment: Do you mind posting something you tried ?

Comment: I used ks1322 solution and I was think more broadly at first, like looking up where the error messages were coming from etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can analyze exit code and print custom message depending on success or failure of `rm`:

```
rm filename 2>/dev/null && echo "You succesfully removed this file!" || echo "Error when removing file"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error manages given by `rm` are part of the `rm` binary installed on the system. 
If you want to change it write a wrapper program that changes the message output when you invoke it.